# ExpressQuantumGrid Excel export of FMTBCD fields without currency symbol and format ",0.00"

Tags: delphi, grid, devexpress

According to this DevExpress Knowledge Base entry for the ExpressQuantumGrid, [Excel-Exports from a cxGrid formats FMTBCD-Fields with a currency-Symbol](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/p/B91868.aspx?searchtext=excel+fmtbcd) it is necessary to use calculated fields of type TFloatField to export FMTBCD fields wihtout the currency symbol to Excel. The example code in the Knowledge Base works as expected.

However I also need to add a precision of two decimal digits in the exported file for the calculated field.

- I tried to use Properties=CalcEdit with DisplayFormat=",0.00" but the export does not use the DisplayFormat of the grid column
- I tried to set the DisplayFormat of the calculated field, but the export does not use the DisplayFormat of the data field

Using version 6.54. (I will also open a support case).

Comment: have you tried to set the property as a cxSpinEdit with type as vtFloat?

Comment: yes, cxSpinEdit did not make a difference

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem wanting to export money values without the currency symbol. The only way I could do it, in the end, was to modify the source code.

I took a copy of cxGridExportLink.pas and put it in a project specific directory. Then changed line 767 (I'm using their subscription number 53 at the moment. Not sure what version that is) but it is the following line:

```
if (IsCurrencyItem(AItem)...
  ... then
  VarCast(Result, AValue, varCurrency);   // <--- This line
```

I changed varCurrency to varDouble and rebuilt my program. You'll also need a copy of cxVer.inc in the same directory.

This may well affect your 2 decimal digits requirement but it's the only way I found and it works well, so far, for us.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is in the Knowledge database (since 2006):

[Export - Excel - export numeric data as numbers with the same format as in the grid](http://www.devexpress.com/scid=A2220)

Maybe it will be fixed in the future.